# PHP, server isset, make form input do nothing if empty and execute code if there is any input on it (its a databse search engine)

Tags: php

ok as the title says, please take a look at the code im using:

```
$search=$_POST['search'];
$query = $pdo->prepare("select * from exportitems where partn LIKE '%$search%' OR manufacturer LIKE '%$search%'");
$query->bindValue(1, "%$search%", PDO::PARAM_STR);    
$query->execute();
if(isset($_POST['search']) || empty($_POST['search']))
{
echo "<center>WRITE SOMETHING IN THE SEARCH FIELD</center><br/>";
}
else if (!$query->rowCount() == 0) {
echo "<center>Search results</center><br/>";
echo "<table style=\"font-family:arial;color:#ffffff;\">";  
echo "<tr><td style=\"border-style:solid;border-width:1px;border-color:#98bf21;background:#000000;\">PART NUMBER</td><td style=\"border-style:solid;border-width:1px;border-color:#000000;background:#000000;\">MANUFACTURER</td><td style=\"border-style:solid;border-width:1px;border-color:#000000;background:#000000;\">DETAILS</td></tr>";             
while ($results = $query->fetch()) {
echo "<tr><td style=\"border-style:solid;border-width:1px;border-color:#000000;\">";            
echo $results['partn'];
echo "</td><td style=\"border-style:solid;border-width:1px;border-color:#000000;\">";
echo $results['manufacturer'];
echo "</td><td style=\"border-style:solid;border-width:1px;border-color:#000000;\">";
echo $results['details'];
echo "</td></tr>";
}
echo "</table>";        
} else {
echo "<center>NO RESULT FOUND</center><br/>";
}
?>
```

the problem im having appears when doing the query, it only executes:

```
if(isset($_POST['search']) || empty($_POST['search']))
{
echo "<center>WRITE SOMETHING IN THE SEARCH FIELD</center><br/>";
}
```

and ignores the rest, so no matter if the field is empty, or anything is written on it, it wont execute the code and get stuck on there.

BUT if i use this code only:

```
$query->execute();
if (!$query->rowCount() == 0) {
echo "<center>Search results</center><br/>";
echo "<table style=\"font-family:verdana;color:#ffffff;\">";    
echo "<tr><td style=\"border-style:solid;border-width:1px;border-color:#98bf21;background:#000000;\">PART NUMBER</td><td style=\"border-style:solid;border-width:1px;border-color:#000000;background:#000000;\">MANUFACTURER</td><td style=\"border-style:solid;border-width:1px;border-color:#000000;background:#000000;\">DETAILS</td></tr>";             
while ($results = $query->fetch()) {
echo "<tr><td style=\"border-style:solid;border-width:1px;border-color:#000000;\">";            
echo $results['partn'];
echo "</td><td style=\"border-style:solid;border-width:1px;border-color:#000000;\">";
echo $results['manufacturer'];
echo "</td><td style=\"border-style:solid;border-width:1px;border-color:#000000;\">";
echo $results['details'];
echo "</td></tr>";
}
echo "</table>";        
} else {
echo "<center>NO RESULT FOUND</center><br/>";
}
?>
```

the search script will work properly EXCEPT for the fact that if the form search field have no characteres and the search button is pressed, the result will output the whole database as a result, making it a security flaw.

any idea of what i'm doing wrong??

thanks in advance.

p.s.: i searched for similar solutions on the community BUT nothing appeared to be this specific case.

Comment: Not recommended lot of logical errors .. here.. just read line by line

Comment: You can use `boolean array_key_exists( mixed $key, array $array)`.

Comment: why do you perform the search first, and only afterwards check for an empty value??

Comment: `bindValue(1, "%$search%"` works??

Comment: i kinda messed up but now its ok, Pipe pointed my mistake and i learned from all others posts, i'm always confused with the isset stuff..

Comment: @chris85 yep, it works flawlessly

Comment: I don't see how that could be, there are no a placeholders. It could be `select * from exportitems where partn LIKE ? OR manufacturer LIKE ?`. Then `$query->execute(array('%$search%', '%$search%'));` or you can name each placeholder and bind separately. Current syntax is incorrect though.

Comment: You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php). I see that you are trying to use [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), but you aren't. You are still concatenating your query, un-escaped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

with

```
if(isset($_POST['search']) || empty($_POST['search']))
```

You are saying if exist or don't has a value write this... this will happen *always*.

Just check the empty state

```
if(empty($_POST['search']))
```

Comment: thanks for pointing this up, it worked like a charm. in 6 minutes ill mark this as green.

Comment: You do realise that an `empty()` does an implied `isset()` as part of its fnctionalitly?  [From manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) _No warning is generated if the variable does not exist. That means empty() is essentially the concise equivalent to !isset($var) || $var == false._

Answer (score 4):

Your `if` statement is asking "**is the value set** or is it empty?"

In other words "is it something, or is it nothing?"

To which the answer is, of course, "yes".

`empty` implies `!isset` as part of its tests, you don't need to duplicate the work.
Just `if( empty($thing)) throw error` will do.

You will want to fix your query though. You're doing prepared statements wrong...

Answer (score 1):

`isset($_POST['search'])` will always return `true` because it'll receive empty string when user doesn't enter anything into the field.

Next thing is that you are executing query and then checking if you've got anything to search for.

Answer (score 0):

```
    if(isset($_POST['search']) && !empty($_POST['search']))
        {
    //Only process the search query when its posted and yah its not empty
            $search=$_POST['search'];
            $query = $pdo->prepare("select * from exportitems where partn LIKE '%$search%' OR manufacturer LIKE '%$search%'");
            $query->bindValue(1, "%$search%", PDO::PARAM_STR);    
            $query->execute();
            if (!$query->rowCount() == 0) {
 //After query has been executed get the row count  which you were doing right   
                echo "<center>Search results</center><br/>";
                echo "<table style=\"font-family:arial;color:#ffffff;\">";  
                echo "<tr><td style=\"border-style:solid;border-width:1px;border-color:#98bf21;background:#000000;\">PART NUMBER</td><td style=\"border-style:solid;border-width:1px;border-color:#000000;background:#000000;\">MANUFACTURER</td><td style=\"border-style:solid;border-width:1px;border-color:#000000;background:#000000;\">DETAILS</td></tr>";             
                while ($results = $query->fetch()) {
                    echo "<tr><td style=\"border-style:solid;border-width:1px;border-color:#000000;\">";            
                    echo $results['partn'];
                    echo "</td><td style=\"border-style:solid;border-width:1px;border-color:#000000;\">";
                    echo $results['manufacturer'];
                    echo "</td><td style=\"border-style:solid;border-width:1px;border-color:#000000;\">";
                    echo $results['details'];
                    echo "</td></tr>";
                }
                echo "</table>";        
            } else {
                echo "<center>NO RESULT FOUND</center><br/>";
            }
        } else {
    //if its not posted or either empty show the warning message
            echo "<center>WRITE SOMETHING IN THE SEARCH FIELD</center><br/>";
        }

    Read tutorials....
```

Comment: An explanation of what you have changed and why, might be good?

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
$len = 0;
if (array_key_exists('search', $_POST)) {
    $search = $_POST['search'];
    $search = trim($search); // optional: if you want remove first and last space
    $len = strlen($_POST['search']);
}

if ($len === 0) {
    // do something
} else {
    // do something
}
```

- `array_key_exists` check if key exist in array(or variable array).
- `isset`check if variable is set.